# Why sometimes with Apache Flink, different keys assigned to the same window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Here I'm feeding the following events to Flink

```java
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:01.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:02.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:03.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:06.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:07.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(5, 5, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:07.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(5, 5, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:09.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(5, 5, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:10.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:04.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(2, 2, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:05.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(5, 5, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:12.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:13.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:15.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:16.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(5, 5, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:11.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:16.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:17.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:15.00Z"), 1));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        ctx.collect(new ClickEvent(1, 1, Instant.parse("2000-05-09T12:00:22.00Z"), 1));
```

And this is my pipeline

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000);
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<ClickEvent> output = env.addSource(source).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks
                (WatermarkStrategy.<ClickEvent>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                        .withTimestampAssigner((click, t) -> click.getEventTimeMillis())).keyBy((ClickEvent e) -> e.userId)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(10000)))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<ClickEvent, ClickEvent, Long, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Long aLong, ProcessWindowFunction<ClickEvent, ClickEvent,                                                                                                                           Long, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<ClickEvent> iterable, Collector<ClickEvent> collector) throws Exception {
                                                            // aLong is the key
                                    // context of the window
                                    // iterable is the content of the window (events)
                                    // collector will be used to emit the output of the window

                                System.out.println("[ Window Start: "+context.window().getStart()+" - Current Watermark: "+
                                        context.currentWatermark() + " - Current Key: "+aLong + " - Window End: "+
                                        context.window().getEnd() + " ]");
                                System.out.println("==== Window Elements ====");
                                for(ClickEvent clickEvent : iterable){
                                    System.out.println(clickEvent.toString());
//                                    collector.collect(clickEvent);
                                }
                    }
                });
        output.print();
        return env.execute("Streaming Job with Global Watermark");
```

I think that each window should work on ONE key at a time, so how different keys are assigned to the same window.

The events that I'm use contains late events and out-of-order events as well.

I'm using the ProcessWindowFunction to display the window elements, window start timestamp, window end timestamp, current watermark and the window key.

```java
[ Window Start: 957873600000 - Current Watermark: 957873610999 - Current Key: 2 - Window End: 957873610000 ]
==== Window Elements ====
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:01Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:02Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:03Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:06Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:07Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:04Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 2, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:05Z, userId= 2, toSum=1}
[ Window Start: 957873600000 - Current Watermark: 957873610999 - Current Key: 5 - Window End: 957873610000 ]
==== Window Elements ====
ClickEvent{ clickId= 5, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:07Z, userId= 5, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 5, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:09Z, userId= 5, toSum=1}
[ Window Start: 957873610000 - Current Watermark: 9223372036854775807 - Current Key: 5 - Window End: 957873620000 ]
==== Window Elements ====
ClickEvent{ clickId= 5, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:10Z, userId= 5, toSum=1}
[ Window Start: 957873610000 - Current Watermark: 9223372036854775807 - Current Key: 1 - Window End: 957873620000 ]
==== Window Elements ====
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:13Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 5, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:12Z, userId= 5, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:15Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 5, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:11Z, userId= 5, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:16Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:16Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:17Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:15Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
[ Window Start: 957873620000 - Current Watermark: 9223372036854775807 - Current Key: 1 - Window End: 957873630000 ]
==== Window Elements ====
ClickEvent{ clickId= 1, clickTimestamp= 2000-05-09T12:00:22Z, userId= 1, toSum=1}
```

Comment: Can You paste the output from Your println too ?

Comment: @DominikWosiński Output added to the question.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when You uncomment `collector.collect(clickEvent)` and do `print` on the stream not from the window process function ?